# Getting NullPointerException on custom Adapter notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-adapter, baseadapter

I have a Custom Adapter and I'm trying to delete an item from it after I call `notifyDataSetChanged()` I get a `nullPointerExeption`.

I want to delete data from the DB so I'm passing an OnClickListener to the adapter so I can later get the info needed to know what to delete.

Here is my code:

**Fragment with the ListView:**

```
        adapter = new TransactionAdapter(getActivity(), values,currency);
        adapter.setButtonOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RelativeLayout l = (RelativeLayout) v.getParent();
                String id_string = ((TextView) l.findViewById(R.id.transaction_id)).getText() +"";
                int id = Integer.parseInt(id_string);
                //Remove from DB
                if(adapter.remove(id)){
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "deleted entry - "+ id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Adapter:**

public class TransactionAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;

```
private OnClickListener onClickListener;
private List<Transaction> listTransaction;

private String currency;

public TransactionAdapter(Context context, List<Transaction> listTransaction, String currency) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listTransaction = listTransaction;
    this.currency = currency;
}

public void setButtonOnClickListener(OnClickListener c){
    onClickListener = c;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.transaction_item_layout, null);
    }
    convertView.setClickable(false);
    Transaction entry = listTransaction.get(position);
    TextView tvDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
    String description = entry.getDescription();
    if(description == null){
        description = "Description Filler";
    }
    tvDescription.setText(description);

    TextView tvAmount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.amount);

    Boolean expense = entry.getExpense();
    if(expense) {
        tvAmount.setText("- " + entry.getAmount().toString() + currency);
        tvAmount.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.buttons_color_delete));
    }else{
        tvAmount.setText("+ " + entry.getAmount().toString() + currency);
        tvAmount.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.second_elements_color));
    }

    TextView tvID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.transaction_id);
    tvID.setText(entry.getId()+"");

    // Set the onClick Listener on this button
    Button btnRemove = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnRemove);
    btnRemove.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    btnRemove.setTag(entry);
    btnRemove.setId(position);


    return convertView;
}

public boolean remove(int id){
    for (int i = 0; i < listTransaction.size(); i++) {
        Transaction t = listTransaction.get(i);
        if(id == t.getId()){
            listTransaction.remove(i);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Item_layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/transaction_item"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_create_budget">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/create_budget_edit_text"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/start_date" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/transaction_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="id"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/amount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnRemove"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnRemove"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@color/create_budget_edit_text"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="23.05€" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRemove"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:text="R" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the **StackTrace**:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void     android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at TransactionAdapter.getView(TransactionAdapter.java:75)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2344)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1344)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1651)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2148)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:887)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
        at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:494)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2072)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1829)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Thanks!

Comment: u cant use onclick listener with adapter

Comment: Can you check if you're using the correct id of the button here : `Button btnRemove = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnRemove);` There should be a button in `R.layout.transaction_item_layout` with the id `btnRemove`.

Comment: @ShivamVerma yes, the id is correct. I've added the layout to the question.

Comment: @raj even if the listener is for the button that is within the item's layout?

Comment: They're talking about the first listener. The listener on your adapter. Inside the adapter, a click listener is fine.

Comment: @ShivamVerma oh then they probably misread the code. The listener I'm passing the adapter is being set on the remove button.

Comment: But the problem is that you can't set `View.OnClickListener` on the adapter. You need to set `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` as mentioned by Alex below.

Comment: @ShivamVerma that was a bad choice of method name on my part, the listener wasn't being set on the adapter. I've updated my question

Comment: Which line is line 75? That's where your problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that I was adding and ID progamatically and It was in conflict with other IDs

On the Adapter I was doing:

```
    btnRemove = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnRemove);
    btnRemove.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    btnRemove.setTag(entry);
    btnRemove.setId(position);
```

Code that I had used from a tutorial, after I removed that `setId`and just used the id in the xml everything worked.

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong type of OnClickListener!

Here is what my code looks like:

```
receiverList = dbTools.getAllReceivers();
dbTools.close();
listView = getListView();
if(receiverList.size() != 0) {
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int index, long id) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.receiverId);

        setReceiverSelection(Integer.valueOf(textView.getText().toString()));
            ((SimpleAdapter) getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    SimpleAdapter adapter = getNewAdapter();
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

You need to use `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()`. In its `onItemClick()` method, you'll get the `view` and `index` of the row that was clicked.

Hope this helps. Good luck :)

EDIT:

If you are looking to have a listener on the button in the row, this is the easiest way to do it.

In the XML for the added rows, add `android:onClick="methodName"` to the XML for the Button.

Then in the activity where you have your `ListView`, add the bottom, add a method called `methodName` which takes a `View` as a parameter. It'll look like this.

```
public void methodName(View view) {

}
```

Now inside of that, we'll want to figure out which row had it's button pressed.

I did that this way:

```
public void methodName(View view) {

    LinearLayout vwParentRow = (LinearLayout)view.getParent();
    TextView recId = (TextView) vwParentRow.findViewById(R.id.receiverId);

    System.out.println(recId.getText().toString() + " had its button pressed!");

}
```

If your button is 'buried' deeper (like if you have a `LinearLayout` inside of your `LinearLayout` and the button is inside of that, just get the parent of the parent:

```
LinearLayout parentOfParent = (LinearLayout) vwParentRow.getParent();
```

EDIT2: 
You can also add a listener programmatically as far as I know and have it do the same thing `onClick` as I showed you in `methodName`. The way I showed definitely works - I used it in my app.

Comment: Even if The listener is for the Button that is contained in the item?

Comment: See my updated response. That's how I did it. If it's the correct answer/it helps you, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks, Let me try that

Comment: Your EDIT2 is what I'm doing originally in my question. Isn't it?

Comment: That didn't work. because I'm using fragments and the on click method would go to the main activity where I don't have access to half of what I need. But is still help me found the right solution!

It still helped me because it threw an `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x1`and after some googling I found the solution